# TextGUI for chat application.getText() returns null

Tags: java, swing

For one reason getText() returns null.For example:

```
   somebody:hi!
```

appears as

```
    null:hi!
```

I have a button which you have to press in order to change the name,but it still returns null as if nothing is written in the JTextField.If I dont' put the button and just use:

```
     username=getText();
```

it appears as :

```
     :hi!
```

Here is my code(yes I agree the layout is awful,but currently I am trying just to make it work):

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.Socket;
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.logging.Level;
  import java.util.logging.Logger;

  public class TextClient extends JFrame{
  public JPanel mypanel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
public static JButton send=new JButton("Send");
public static JButton changename=new JButton("Change name");
public static JTextField textf=new JTextField(10);
public static JTextField textname=new JTextField(10);
public static JLabel username=new JLabel("Name:");
public static JTextArea texta=new JTextArea(20,20);
public static JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(texta);
public String user;
public TextClient() throws IOException
{
   add(mypanel);
        GridBagConstraints c1=new GridBagConstraints();
        c1.anchor=GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        c1.gridx=3;
        c1.gridy=1;
        mypanel.add(textf,c1);
        GridBagConstraints c2=new GridBagConstraints();
        c2.gridx=2;
        c2.gridy=2;
        mypanel.add(jsp,c2);
        GridBagConstraints c3=new GridBagConstraints();
          c3.gridx=2;
        c3.gridy=0;

       mypanel.add(send,c3);
       GridBagConstraints c4=new GridBagConstraints();
       c4.gridx=0;
       c4.gridy=0;
       mypanel.add(username,c4);
       GridBagConstraints c5=new GridBagConstraints();
       c5.gridx=1;
       c5.gridy=0;

       mypanel.add(textname,c5);
       GridBagConstraints c6=new GridBagConstraints();
       c6.gridx=2;
       c6.gridy=1;
       mypanel.add(changename,c6);


        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);   
        Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",9000);




           changename.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
           {

                user=textname.getText();
           }
       });
       ClientPeer cp=new ClientPeer(user,socket); 
       String message=textf.getText();
        cp.start();

            send.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
                {
                    try {
                        String sendit=textf.getText();
                        cp.sendMessage(sendit);
                        textf.setText("");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(TextClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });



}

public static void main(String [] args)
 {
      try {
          new TextClient();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(TextClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,     null, ex);
      }
  }
 }
```

Comment: @Aify it is the method of JTextField,it is not made by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mixing up objects and variables, and making one call at the wrong time.

Here:

```
   ClientPeer cp=new ClientPeer(user,socket); 
   String message=textf.getText();
```

You call getText() in a constructor and not in an ActionListener, meaning you're making this call before the textf JTextField has even been rendered in a GUI and long before the user has had a chance to fill it.

Here:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
       {

            user=textname.getText();
       }
```

You change the state of the user field inside of an ActionListener, but unfortunately you use the user varable in the first code that I have shown, again **before** the field has been rendered and before the user has interacted with it.

I suggest that you put more of your code, including the code that uses the user variable **inside** your ActionListener code, so that the variable actually holds relevant information.

Other recommendations:

- None of your fields should be declared static. If you feel that they must be static to fix an error, then you're fixing the error backwards. The correct fix is to create code that does not require static fields (with some exceptions of course, but none that apply in your current case).

---

Here's a simplified version of your code, to show you what I mean:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TextClient extends JFrame {
   public JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();
   public JButton send = new JButton("Send");
   public JButton changename = new JButton("Change name");
   public JTextField textf = new JTextField(10);
   public JTextField textname = new JTextField(10);
   public JLabel username = new JLabel("Name:");
   public String user;

   public TextClient() throws IOException {
      add(mypanel);
      mypanel.add(textf);
      mypanel.add(send);
      mypanel.add(username);
      mypanel.add(textname);
      mypanel.add(changename);

      setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      pack();
      setVisible(true);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      changename.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            user = textname.getText();
            System.out.println("user in action listener: " + user);
         }
      });

      // you're trying to use user here!
      System.out.println("user outside of action " 
             + "listener where you try to use it: " + user); // !!

      send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            String sendit = textf.getText();
            System.out.println("sendit: " + sendit);
         }
      });

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         new TextClient();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(TextClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
               ex);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: textf reffers to the message that is being sent ,not to the username(the username is using getText() only in the ActionListener).I do not quite understood what you meant with using the variable in the first code and then in the action listener.

Comment: @DianaLc: I know what textf refers to. I still stand by my findings and recommendation. The bottom line is that you're trying to use the user field **before** the user of your program has a chance to set it or change it, so it of course is null.

Comment: @DianaLc: please see simplified version of code in my answer's edit to show what I mean.

Comment: Thank you,now I understood and modified the code to the output desired and it's working fine.I really appreciate your work.